# how to get the height and width of image in javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, image

I have a code where I am trying to get all images tag height and width.

```
var img = $('.data').find('img');
$.each($(img), function() {
console.log('first', this.height, $(this).height, $(this).height());
console.log('second', $(this).clientHeight, $(this).naturalHeight);
console.log('third',  $(this)[0].height,  $(this)[0].clientHeight,  $(this)[0].naturalHeight);
console.log($(this).attr('height'), $(this).prop('height'));                                                                                                     });
```

> Even i tried for `img` in loop.
>
> tried the same with width , the result will be either 0 or undefined.
>   tried same thing for `width`.

**Can you tell me where I am doing wrong**

Answer (score 1):

You are passing `$(img)` this should be only `img` inside you `$.each`.Also you where printing `console.log('first',..` instead of this if your image has `name` attribute use that .

Here is demo code :

```js
var img = $('.data').find('img');
$.each(img, function() {
  console.log($(this).attr("name") + "-> Height: " + $(this)[0].height + " Width:" + $(this)[0].width);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="data">
  <img name="image1" src=" https://twimg0-a.akamaihd.net/a/1350072692/t1/img/front_page/jp-mountain@2x.jpg" style="height:70px;width:70px">
  <img name="image2" src=" https://twimg0-a.akamaihd.net/a/1350072692/t1/img/front_page/jp-mountain@2x.jpg" style="height:40px;width:40px">
  <img name="image3" src=" https://twimg0-a.akamaihd.net/a/1350072692/t1/img/front_page/jp-mountain@2x.jpg" style="height:50px;width:50px">
</div>
```

Comment: thank you for replying, even i tried for img , but the result is same

Answer (score 0):

i was not getting the height and width of an image because the image `load` event happens very late in the load process

Finally I found an answer

```
var img = $('.data').find('img');
$.each(img, function() {
  $(this).bind('load', function() { 
    console.log($(this).height);
  }
});
```

it worked for both `img` and `$(img)`